# Unknown field error in Django model form for User model

Tags: python, django

This is what I am trying

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:

    model=User

    fields=(' electricity','natural_gas','heating_oil','coal','lpg','propane','wooden_pellets')
```

And this is the error code

```
raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (propane, heating_oil, wooden_pellets, lpg, coal,  electricity, natural_gas) specified for User
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO! Could you add some context, what is the code that is generating the `FieldError`, provide a bit more context: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @sohail fields mentioned in `fields` param of `Meta` are not part of `django.contrib.auth.models.User`
if you want to add non model field to form you can add them like `electricity = forms.IntegerField()`

Comment: Where have you defined those fields in your models? The default `User` model does not have those fields, so that form will not work with `model = User`.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing User given by django here

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

It has following fields

```
id
password
last_login
is_superuser
username
first_name
last_name
email
is_staff
is_active
date_joined
```

In your `UserForm` inside meta class you specified model as User and trying to access fields

```
fields=(' electricity','natural_gas','heating_oil','coal','lpg','propane','wooden_pellets')
```

which clearly are not there.

Maybe you want to refer to some other model. You can also create a user you like with above fields if you inherit from django `User` model class like:

```
class MyUser(User):
    electricity= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #your fields here
```

and specify in meta of UserForm as `model = MyUser`